# When i minimize windows in IE elements are not shown

Tags: html, css

I have portal with reports. Each report has drop downs with fixed width=130px. Everything is ok, but when i try to minimize the window some of the elements are not shown on the page. My code is following

```
 <tr valign="bottom" style="height: 10px">
            <td width="20px" style="vertical-align: top">
            </td>
            <td width="30px" style="vertical-align: middle" align="right" nowrap="nowrap">
                <label>
                    @Html.Resource("Reports_Brand")</label>
            </td>
            <td width="130px" style="vertical-align: middle" align="left">
                @Html.DropdownField("Reports_Brand", Portal.Framework.Mvc.ViewDataPreparers.BrandsPreparerW.ViewDataKey, 2, new { style = "width:130px;" })
            </td>
            <td width="30px" style="vertical-align: middle" align="right" nowrap="nowrap">
                <label>
                    @Html.Resource("Reports_Portal")</label>
            </td>
            <td width="130px" style="vertical-align: middle" align="left">
                @Html.DropdownField("Reports_Portal", Portal.Framework.Mvc.ViewDataPreparers.PortalsPreparerW.ViewDataKey, 2, new { style = "width:130px;" })
            </td>
            <td width="30px" style="vertical-align: middle" align="right" nowrap="nowrap">
                <label>
                    @Html.Resource("Default_Language")</label>
            </td>
            <td width="30px" style="vertical-align: middle" align="left">
                @Html.DropdownField("Reports_Language", Portal.Framework.Mvc.ViewDataPreparers.LanguagesPreparerW.ViewDataKey, 2, new { style = "width:130px;" })
            </td>
            <td width="30px" style="vertical-align: middle" align="right" nowrap="nowrap">
                <label>
                    @Html.Resource("Reports_PlayerProductType")</label>
            </td>
            <td width="30px" style="vertical-align: middle" align="right" nowrap>
                @Html.DropdownField("Reports_PlayerProductType", Portal.Framework.Mvc.ViewDataPreparers.ProductTypesPreparerW.ViewDataKey, 2, new { style = "width:130px;" })
            </td>
            <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
```

What i can do to stay each drop down on the page, even if i change the windows size ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving the width in pixels, try setting the width of the elements in percentage(%). This way the elements will get adjusted according to the size of the window.

Comment: I also tried that but doesn't work fine for me. I think that problem is that i have all drop downs in table <td>.

Comment: Have you tried changing the width of <td> to percentage also?

Comment: Yes and it's the same. Without changes

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/L2vp9dpj/2/). Check if it fits your requirement.

Comment: Ok now try to change/make it smaller the window and you will see that the drop downs from the right side  are disappearing

Comment: I suggest you to use responsive design for that. Here is the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L2vp9dpj/3/). This will adjust the drop downs according to the window size.